# How to use Shopify api to update the cart "Note" from the "Additional content & scripts" box

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, shopify

I need to add a Note after the user places their order and is sent to the confirmation page.  I know you can add code in the "Additional content & scripts" and was wondering if anyone knew how to add an ajax call that would allow me to add a note to the order through there?

**Something like**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {
      note: "NEW ORDER CUSTOM NOTE",
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is what you do. Setup an App to listen for the Webhook event that the order was (created|paid). Use the API to get the order. Add your note to it.

Otherwise, if you want the customer to see the note on the confirmation page, you have the option to do a callback on the confirmation page to your App, using a Proxy, and get the note, to display. You could also inject a script tag that runs there, to display some generic note.

You don't provide enough details on your true intentions to describe more or better options. Clearly your code approach is never gonna fly as it is pre-order. Your code would work though to append a note to the cart which is then part and parcel of the order.

Comment: Hi David.  The goal of the feature would be to allow us to automatically add notes to orders after the customer places the order based on conditions such as "is the user a first time user".  So the workflow would be new user goes through checkout and places order > order confirmation screen has logic that looks to see if the user is a first time user (does the user have more then one order) > if the user is a first time user there would be a custom message added to the order letting the shipping team know they need to add a specific marketing form.

Comment: So use an App that listens to the orders/create or orders/paid webhook, and use that opportunity to look up the customer, and decide on the note. Simple.